# Update git commit email address for a commit in the past

Tags: git, gitlab

I was working on a branch and made several commits. `git log` looks like this:

```
commit drginrd45345eff34wfe... (HEAD -> peterdoe/my-new-branch)
Author: Peter Doe <peterdoe@xyzcom>
Date:   Fri Jul 6 19:10:12 2021 +0200

    update3

commit rey4tgrege45ge343rg...
Author: Peter Doe <peterdoe@peterdoe.dev.xyz.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 5 18:12:43 2021 +0200

    update2

commit 6745trge4te4t4t4t4g...
Author: Peter Doe <peterdoe@xyz.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 5 11:21:12 2021 +0200

    update1
```

I can not push my branch to open merge request as the author email on `update2` is not the same as the other two commits. How can I update the author email for commit `rey4tgrege45ge343rg` to also be `peterdoe@xyz.com`, while changing nothing else so I can open my MR with all three commits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the changes are on your own branch, you can safely re-write history to change the commit author.

In your case you can start an interactive rebase starting with the commit you want to change from the terminal with

```
git rebase -i -p rey4tgr
```

You will be able to mark the commits you want to edit and then git will walk you through each commit asking you to make your changes. For changing the author email you can use

```
git commit --amend --author="Peter Doe <peterdoe@xyz.com>" --no-edit
git rebase --continue
```

And do this until you have made all the changes you want.

Comment: After running a `git rebase -i -p rey4tgr`, a file is opened. Should I add `git commit --amend --author="Peter Doe <peterdoe@xyz.com>" --no-edit` to the end of the file or exit the file and then run the command?

Comment: The file that is opened allows you to select which commits you want to change.

Comment: Gotcha! But should the `--amend` and `--continue` commands be added to the file or run after closing the file?

Comment: Run them after closing the file